# Pausing Logstash During Synonym Updates

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, logstash, opensearch

I'm currently engaged in a project that utilizes Elastic Search. Within this project, I've established a logstash pipeline that operates at 10-second intervals to ensure the synchronization of data between the Elastic Search index and my PostgreSQL database. A significant aspect of my work involves leveraging the synonym feature in Elastic Search, specifically with Amazon OpenSearch. To facilitate this, I've developed an API responsible for updating and associating my synonym file within the Amazon OpenSearch environment.

However, there's a noteworthy consideration to be aware of. The process of linking the synonym file necessitates the opening and closing of the Elastic Search index. This introduces the potential for a temporary closure of the index during the synchronization of data from my PostgreSQL database. Consequently, there exists a risk that certain data might not be successfully entered into the database during this period, which is a situation I'm keen on avoiding.

I've implemented a cron job to manage the updating of synonyms in Amazon OpenSearch. This cron job is configured to run every 5 minutes. Simultaneously, the ElasticSearch schedule is set to execute every 10 seconds. To ensure the seamless synchronization of data without any gaps, I'm finding a solution to temporarily pause the logstash pipeline when the synonym update cron job is active. I want to safeguard against data loss and guarantee the accurate synchronization of information between Elastic Search and the PostgreSQL database.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or insights. :)